# How to set PyCharm external tools?

Tags: ide, environment-variables, pycharm

I want to run `mypy` for type checking before executing my script. Here is my configuration,

[image]

But I got only,

```
<path-to-project>/venv/bin/mypy --disallow-untyped-defs /
There are no .py[i] files in directory '/'
```

The environment variables were not replaced. So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Answered similar question on [Pycharm Run External Tool Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424711/pycharm-run-external-tool-macro?rq=1)

TL;DR:
External Tools $FilePath$ macro fails to inject arguments into mypy executable. File Watchers $FilePath$ macro succeeds.

Reference for File Watchers : https://www.alexkorablev.com/mypy-python-27.html
it is for Python2.7 but the idea is the same for configuring file watchers.