# Pycharm Run External Tool Macro

Tags: pycharm, mypy

I am trying to run mypy as a "Before Launch" tool in the Run Configuration as a Template.

I have the following settings (Program: is the path to the mypy executible).

When I run my script I expect the macro to insert the filename of the script as so:

```
mypy.exe myScript.py
```

however it is only running the mypy.exe part (in the console I get an error telling me to supply the target script to the function). I have also tried deleting the working directory field as well, to no avail:

(Win10 / Python3.6 / Miniconda)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing similar behavior with version:
`PyCharm 2018.2.5 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-182.5107.22, built on November 13, 2018`

**External Tools**

It seems that the macro `$FilePath$` is not being injected as an argument into the `mypy` executable.
The only one I have tried which does get injected is `$PyInterpreterDirectory`.

**File Watchers**

Another workaround to this is adding `mypy` to file watchers. This will allow you to display `mypy` analysis of the current file, each time you save the file.

**File > Settings > Tools > File Watchers** : *From here add the `mypy` executable and the argument.*

**TL;DR:**

**External Tools** `$FilePath$` macro fails to inject arguments into `mypy` executable.
**File Watchers** `$FilePath$` macro succeeds.

Reference for File Watchers : https://www.alexkorablev.com/mypy-python-27.html
it is for Python2.7 but the idea is the same for configuring file watchers.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code at the end of the module (probably not the best way, but when you have a small module and want to test things, it does the trick):

```
import os
os.system('python -m mypy <your_file_name>.py')
```